# How to import PyPi library not included in Chaquopy packages?

Tags: python, android, pip, mediapipe, chaquopy

On Running

```
python {
      pip {
         install "mediapipe"
      }
}
```

Error is coming "No Version satisfies rquirement mediapipr(fromVersion:None)" as mediapipe is not in chaquopy packages but it is in pypi.

So my question is How can I import library from PyPi if it is not in chauopy packages

I want to use python in my app in android studio. So I downloaded chaquopy in android studio and implented it.
I have to add 4 libraries cv2, mediapipe, matplotlib and numpy of which I added 3 of these by using

```
python {
      pip {
         install "library-name"
      }
}
```

But got error as it is not in chaquopy packages

Comment: See: https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/479 as it appears `mediapipe` isn't a supported package.